# Best way to transform a huge CSV file content into quickly queryable data store?

Tags: java, database, csv, amazon-s3, datastore

Have a requirement to allow web user to upload a CSV file with around 10millions of Customer Ids in it. This data must be later used on serving certain other app content to Customer if he/she present in the CSV file. The System expects thousands of customer requests in this fashion, so the backend needs to scale - The ask here is, what is the best way to transform the CSV into any specific DB/S3 in the backend and so it allows an easy filtering? Storing and parsing the file each time is not viable, so looking to understand any best possible ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/what-is.html) or Amazon [S3 Select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-select.html).

**Amazon Athena** is a query engine that can read data directly from (multiple) files stored in Amazon S3. It works best when the files are in a columnar format (eg Parquet or ORC) and compressed, but it can work on normal CSV files too. It is highly scalable, especially where multiple files are being queried. However, it treats data as being stored in a 'table' based on its location in S3, so it isn't ideal for querying random files.

**Amazon S3 Select** only works on a single file at a time, but it can directly query a CSV file (and a few other formats). It has an SQL-like query capability.

If your need is to query a different file each time, I would recommend S3 Select.

The benefit of both of these options is that you do *not* need to 'load' the data into a database. However, that is certainly an option you might consider if you need very fast access to the data. (Amazon Redshift can handle billions of rows in a table quite quickly, but it is more expensive.)

Comment: Thanks John for quick response, Amazon S3 Select seems a way to go for me as I need to for Single file at a time.

Comment: Adding to John's great answer - One pattern to consider is loading your data into Redshift and storing it back to S3 as Parquet in a partitioned organization.  This file format w/ partitioning can greatly improve performance for tools like Athena.  While this transform can be done by other tools, Redshift gives you the ability to transform data, merge data, and deduplicate data that is difficult to do with file-by-file processes.  You will not want to run Redshift continuously as it can get expensive but for a once per day ingestion of new data this can be a good pattern.

Comment: Good idea, @BillWeiner! This can also be done in Athena ([Converting to Columnar Formats - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/convert-to-columnar.html)). I do this for my data, which makes it fast and low-cast for querying in Athena.

Comment: That's really a conversion of CSV to Parquet in EMR/HIVE, not Athena, for use by Athena.  It would be interesting to see a price/performance comparison between these conversion processes.  My experience would lead me to guess that RS is cheaper (for the same processing time) but only if you have the cluster up.  A temporal RS pattern suffers from boot up time which likely puts it behind in this use case.  Just my guess and data would be interesting

Comment: Oops! In that case, use [Using AWS Athena To Convert A CSV File To Parquet | CloudForecast Blog](https://www.cloudforecast.io/blog/Athena-to-transform-CSV-to-Parquet/). I do it with a simple `CREATE TABLE AS`, selecting from the CSV table into a new Parquet, Snappy, Partitioned table -- all within Athena. Makes future querying great!